# Copy of store not updated when mounted Async axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have been struggling with this issue for a day now. I want to make a copy of the store for `user` into `userCopy` so that it can be edited by the user without causing a mutation. My problem is that even though I am using the mounted hook, `userCopy` only returns an empty store state.

**pages/settings/_id.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ user }} // will display the whole object 
    {{ userCopy }} // will only display empty store object
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import _ from 'lodash'

data() {
  return {
    userCopy: {}
  }
},

computed: {
   ...mapState({ user: (state) => state.staff.user })
},
created() {
   this.$store.dispatch('staff/fetchUser', this.$route.params.id)
},

mounted() {
   this.$data.userCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.staff.user)
},
</script>
```

**store/staff.js**

```
import StaffService from '~/services/StaffService.js'
export const state = () => ({
  user: {
    offers: '',
    legal: ''
  }
})
export const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
}

export const actions = {

  fetchUser({ commit, getters }, id) {
    const user = getters.getUserById(id)

    if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', user)
    } else {
      StaffService.getUser(id) // StaffService users axios get call
        .then((response) => {
          commit('SET_USER', response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('There was an error:', error.response)
        })
    }
  },

}

export const getters = {
  getUserById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.staff.find((user) => user.id === id)
  }
}
```

Even using this mounted method did not solve the issue. The `userCopy` object still returns empty.

```
 mounted() {
    this.$store
      .dispatch('staff/fetchUser', this.$route.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.userCopy = this.$store.state.staff.user
      })
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a getter for this purpose?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I already have a getter for ``getUserById``

Comment: I see, you can directly use it in you component where you use your _ function

Comment: Can you show me how please. I am still getting the hang of Vue and Vuex

Comment: Of course, also 'cause getters in namespaced modules used in components are not so well documented.  If you are using your store module namespaced, to call the getter from the component it should be:

`this.$store.getters['StaffService/getUserById'](id)`

Comment: ``this.$data.userCopy = _.cloneDeep(
      this.$store.getters['staff/getUserById'](this.$route.params.id)
    )`` now ``userCopy`` is undefined.

Comment: try to console.log  `this.$store.getters['staff/getUserById'](this.$route.params.id)` to see if the problem is in the getter returning undefined

Comment: Yep the getter returning ``undefined``. Whats the benefit of using a getter instead of an action?

Comment: Oh man, forget whatever I told you. Now when you asked about the actions getters difference I checked again and I see why is empty... I put it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the mounted() is called before your network request get solved.
To fix this, I suggest to do like this.
First:

```
if (user) {
   console.log('user found',user)
  commit('SET_USER', user)
  return user
} else {
    console.log('user not found')

    //RETURN the Axios Call here
    return StaffService.getUser(id) // StaffService users axios get call
    .then((response) => {
      commit('SET_USER', response.data)

      //return the response here, after committing
      return response.data
    })
```

then in your component

```
 mounted() {
    this.$store
      .dispatch('staff/fetchUser', this.$route.params.id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.userCopy = response
      })
  }
```

Comment: hmm. the ``userCopy`` still is undefined.

Comment: the         console.log(response)
in the component too?

Comment: Yes the the console.log(response)  is also undefined.

Comment: return the user also here:

`if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', user)
      return user`

Comment: the ``userCopy`` still is undefined.

Comment: the console.log(response) in the component too?

Comment: Yes thats where i am receiving undefined from

Comment: I update my answer for debug. It seems your action is not returning correctly and this cause all undefined and empty issues

Comment: ``user not found`` console log from cache,  now the data is loading... and mounted response now returns ``[object Object]`` I think what made it work was returning the whole axios call.

Comment: So it's solved, it seems. Now your user is not undefined. As you see from the `user not found` message, the problem was that you was not returning your axios call.

Comment: Yes thank you. Now my next issue is props not being set when the component is loaded.... :(

Comment: Check how the props are passed (and when :) ) and in case, after a research here, open a new question with the detailed code and feel free to pm me the question link

Comment: Thank you :). I have objects within the store  USER that needed to be defined. My next task is to put/post updated values for the user.